# Top command output for Virtual or Physical Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, top

Does top output display information particular to the VM I am in, or the entire physical machine?

```
top - 17:22:04 up 22:37,  1 user,  load average: 72.55, 73.18, 66.84
Tasks: 140 total,   1 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 98.1 us,  1.6 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 16266748 total, 13817608 free,  1354756 used,  1094384 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8257532 total,  8257532 free,        0 used. 14582984 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                               
13742 mysql     20   0 2748260 864628   9448 S 399.7  5.3   3434:55 mysqld                                                                                                                                
18981 root      20   0  162032   2320   1596 R   0.7  0.0   0:00.07 top                                                                                                                                   
 5212 root      20   0  126284   1704   1068 S   0.3  0.0   0:01.41 crond
```

So here you see CPU usage at 98% - which is insane.

> Is this for the VM or the iron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top will show utilization of the OS. I think your vm using 4 CPUS, and mysql running 399% cpu usage, it means 98% of total CPU.

Comment: The MySQL issue is being handled separately. :^)